# Is the following definition of maximum and minimum values (given by textbook) correct?

Tags: calculus, notation, definition

Consider the following definition from the chapter titled [APPLICATION OF DERIVATIVES](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lemh106.pdf#page=24), encompassing minimum value, maximum value, extreme value and their corresponding points in an interval of domain of a function

> Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval $I$. Then
>
> (a) $f$ is said to have a maximum value in $I$, if there exists a
> point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c) > f(x)$, for all $x \in I$.
>
> The number $f(c)$ is called the maximum value of $f$ in $I$ and the
> point $c$ is called a point of maximum value of $f$ in $I$.
>
> (b) $f$ is said to have a minimum value in $I$, if there exists a
> point $c$ in $I$ such that $f (c) < f (x)$, for all $x \in I$.
>
> The number $f(c)$, in this case, is called the minimum value of $f$ in
> $I$ and the point $c$, in this case, is called a point of minimum
> value of $f$ in $I$.
>
> (c) $f$ is said to have an extreme value in $I$ if there exists a
> point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c)$ is either a maximum value or a
> minimum value of $f$ in $I$.
>
> The number $f(c)$, in this case, is called an extreme value of $f$ in
> $I$ and the point $c$ is called an extreme point.

Consider either (a) or (b) in the definition. I am taking (a). It is saying that $c \in I$ and checking for $f(c) > f(x)$ for all $x \in I$. Since $c \in I$, we encounter $f(c) > f(c)$, which is always false. So, this definition appears faulty to me and I think there is a need to either change the inequality sign from $>$ to $\ge$ or scope of checking from $I$ to $I -\{c \}$ as follows (for (a)).

> Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval $I$. Then
>
> (a) $f$ is said to have a maximum value in $I$, if there exists a
> point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c) \ge f(x)$, for all $x \in I$.

or

> Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval $I$. Then
>
> (a) $f$ is said to have a maximum value in $I$, if there exists a
> point $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c) > f(x)$, for all $x \in I-\{c\}$.

Am I correct? If no, is the definition given in the textbook true and where am I going wrong in that case?

Comment: You are right, the book is wrong. That should be $f(c)\ge f(x)$. A typo, I suppose.